# Unsupported framebuffer format in ios 8

Tags: ios, ios8, mapkit

The scenario is a basic:
there are 2 view controllers - a plain (nothing but a button in it) and a mapview controller which has mapkit mapview in it.

in the map there is one annotation with a callout that when clicked, pushes the plain view controller to the navigation controller. In the plain controller, when the button is clicked, it pushes the mapview controller (a new instance).

So doing this about 22 times results in the map tiles not being displayed, and the mapview flickers. If going back to a previous map controller, the map displays and operates fine.

When the flicker occurs, this error prints out in the debug several times

```
ERROR /SourceCache/VectorKit/VectorKit-992.19/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1251: Unsupported framebuffer format
```

This was done with ipad 4, ios 8.1.3

Is this a known issue?

Comment: ... so after you've pressed the button 22 times you have 44 view controllers on the navigation stack?

Comment: If you feel this is a bug you should file a radar in apples bug reporter tool.

Comment: @Tommy yes, why is that a problem? The error doesn't indicate the problem is with the navigation controller

Comment: @NickGinanto I'm guessing, which is why this is not an answer, that what's actually happening is a failure to allocate resources owing to the lack of available resources, which is then printed as a very misleading error message. So one part of the stack says "I can't do that" and the other part thinks "Oh, that must mean he can _never_ do that".

Comment: What Tommy said. No wonder the device is unable to render new instances if you keep all previous instances alive.

Comment: @Tommy wouldn't it cause a memory warning instead?

Comment: @NickGinanto not necessarily; memory warnings are generated by the CPU when it expects that applications will be able to free memory. Exhaustion of the GPU memory pool wouldn't necessarily be part of the same mechanism. Again though: all guesses. Would it be possible to use only one map navigation controller and otherwise to backup its state somehow? If so, does that affect the problem?

Comment: I thing you used geocoding i your map, and may be Google limits number of geocoding requests.. Thats why this was happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 21 Map Kit view controllers. Each view controller is setting up a frame buffer to render vector map data. When your device attempts to setup that last view controller it can't allocate one more buffer. But the code continues to execute for a short while longer. Then some other code tries to use that bad buffer, and issues the error that you see.

The way to fix this is to not make so many Map Kit view controllers. Instead of pushing a new view controller use the `- setViewControllers:animated:` method of the `UINavigationController` to swap your two controllers. Where you are now just pushing a new copy of your view controlers, try something like:

```
NSMutableArray *vcArray = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
if (vcArray.count > 1) {
    UIViewController *backVC = vcArray[vcArray.count - 2];
    vcArray[vcArray.count - 2] = self;
    vcArray[vcArray.count - 1] = backVC;
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcArray animated:YES];
} else {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self otherVC] animated:YES];
}
```

This assumes you have a method `-otherVC` that vends the appropriate view controller. This also assumes just these two view controllers are used, so you may want to alter the if statement to fit the logic of your app's functionality.

The only reason I can think of why you really need 21 different Map Kit view controllers is because each needs to display a different location on the map. Use some other method to store the location for each of these view controllers, and then push that information to the one map each time it is displayed. You can save a few values such as the location and magnification of the map instead of all the additional storage needed to setup the full map view controller.